# Java, return method as reference

Tags: java

Im beginner JAVA developer. Here is a method:

```
private Method getSomething()
{
    for (Method m : getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
    {
        return m;
    }
    return notFound;
}

private void notFound()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

it doesnt matter what it does - if it finds something, then returns a `Method` - if not, the `notFound()` method itself should be returned. So the hot spot is at the `return notFound;` line: if I use `return notFound();` then it returns its value, not the method itself. I want something like a reference/pointer. So `getSomething()` returns something what can be called, and if the returned method is used wrong, it should trigger that Exception - so its not an option to replace `return notFound;` with `throw new Exception();` !
Or the 2nd option is to create a lambda method....

Comment: Note that since you return _any_ declared method, you could just coincidentally return `notFound`, as it too is inside `getClass().getDeclaredMethods()`, even though there might be other methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call

`this.getClass().getMethod("notFound")`

to get the `notFound` method of the current/this object's class.

So just do this:

`return this.getClass().getMethod("notFound");`

More details here:

[Class.getMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

**EDIT:**

You can retrieve i.e. get and call private methods too via reflection.

Here is an example.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class Test001 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test002 obj = new Test002();
        Method m = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("testMethod", int.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);

        m.invoke(obj, 10);
        m.invoke(obj, 20);

        System.out.println(m.getName());
    }


}

class Test002 {
    private void testMethod(int x){
        System.out.println("Hello there: " + x);
    }       
}
```

Comment: only disadvantage is "notFound()" cant be private :)

Comment: it works when notFound() but wont if notFound(int parameter);

Comment: As i suggested for you in my post. You should read the topic about this (Reflection). If you want to use e.g. a notFound method with String parameter. This way you can reach it:
    this.getMethod("notFound", new Class[]{String.class});

Comment: @JohnSmith It works for private methods too. You need to just call `setAccessible`. And it works for methods having an int parameter too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use reflection to achieve this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

e.g. to get all methods of a given class:

```
Class aClass = ...//obtain class object
Method[] methods = aClass.getMethods();
```